# Сортировка по выбранному полю

Tags: java, android, сортировка

У объекта 3 поля - дата покупки, цена и качество. Как реализовать 3 сортировки по соответствующим полям через `compareTo()`?

Comment: Вам необходимо использовать именно интерфейс `Comparable`? Или подойдет и `Comparator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример реализации с использованием рефлексии и `Comparator`. Можно адаптировать под использование с `compareTo()`. Полный исходник на [ideone](https://ideone.com/1Ydqaw)

```
class Ideone {
    ...

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name
    private static class MyObjectComparator implements Comparator<Object> {  
        private String getter;

        public MyObjectComparator(String field) {
            this.getter = "get" + field.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.substring(1);
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            try {
                if (o1 != null && o2 != null) {
                    o1 = o1.getClass().getMethod(getter, new Class[0]).invoke(o1, new Object[0]);
                    o2 = o2.getClass().getMethod(getter, new Class[0]).invoke(o2, new Object[0]);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Cannot compare " + o1 + " with " + o2 + " on " + getter, e);
            }

            return (o1 == null) ? -1 : ((o2 == null) ? 1 : ((Comparable<Object>) o1).compareTo(o2));
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        List<MyObject> objs = new ArrayList<>();
        objs.add(new MyObject(sdf.parse("21/12/2015"), 1234, 2));
        objs.add(new MyObject(sdf.parse("12/01/2016"), 134, 4));
        objs.add(new MyObject(sdf.parse("01/01/2012"), 3244, 1));

        System.out.println("Сортировка по качеству:");
        Collections.sort(objs, new MyObjectComparator("quality"));
        System.out.println(objs);

        System.out.println("Сортировка по цене:");
        Collections.sort(objs, new MyObjectComparator("price"));
        System.out.println(objs);

        System.out.println("Сортировка по дате:");
        Collections.sort(objs, new MyObjectComparator("date"));
        System.out.println(objs);
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения:

> Сортировка по качеству:
>   [MyObject[01/01/2012, 3244, 1], MyObject[21/12/2015, 1234, 2], MyObject[12/01/2016, 134, 4]]
>   Сортировка по цене:
>   [MyObject[12/01/2016, 134, 4], MyObject[21/12/2015, 1234, 2], MyObject[01/01/2012, 3244, 1]]
>   Сортировка по дате:
>   [MyObject[01/01/2012, 3244, 1], MyObject[21/12/2015, 1234, 2], MyObject[12/01/2016, 134, 4]]